# Unable to retrieve a collection in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello i'm learning hibernate and attempting to persist to the database. But i'm having a problem. I have a User entity and was successful in creating the table. The next requirement is a user can be friends with other users. And the friendship is bidirectional. A user can have zero or more friends. My approach is to use a one to many relationship since a user can have multiple users as friends. Please correct me if my approach is wrong. I used a collection of users as it was easier to maintain indexes as an array list works perfectly. I am able to add a friend to the list but when i try to get a certain user from the URL, it doesn't display the friends list. And also after adding a friend from a certain id, if i try to add another friend it complain cannot use duplicate key of id 1. Please what i am doing wrong. Is my idea wrong. Is it a many to many relationship?

user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String first_name, last_name, description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="Friendship")
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="userOne_Id", referencedColumnName ="user_Id"),
            @JoinColumn(name="user2Id", referencedColumnName = "user_Id")})
    @JsonIgnore
    Collection<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

    public Collection<User> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(Collection<User> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

implementation of creating Friends:

```
public User createFriends(long id1, long id2){

        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        User p1=null, p2=null;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            p1 = session.get(User.class, id1);
             if(p1!=null){ //checks to see if the user exist
                 p2 = session.get(User.class, id2);
                 if(p2!=null) { //checks to see if the friend exist
                     if(!(p1.getFriends().contains(p2))){ 
                          //add user2 to user1 and vice versa..
                         p1.getFriends().add(p2);
                         p2.getFriends().add(p1);
                         session.save(p1);
                         session.save(p2);
                         transaction.commit();
                     }
                     else{
                         //don't do anything friend is already in the list..
                     }
                 }
                 else {
                        return p2; //return null id doesn't exist
                 }
             }
            else{
                 return p1; // id1 doesn't exist
             }
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex){
            if(transaction!=null)
                transaction.rollback();

        }
        finally {
            if(session!=null)
                session.close();
        }
        return p1; //returns the user

    }
```

Retrieving a particular user: unable to retrieve and display friendlist, even though id's are stored in database.

```
public User findById(long id) {

        User user = null;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            user = session.get(User.class, id);
            //to test and see if it works
            System.out.println("Friends Size: "+user.getFriends().size());

        }
        catch(HibernateException ex) {
            if(transaction!=null)
                transaction.rollback();

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(session!=null)
                session.close();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: can you please share the table structure

Comment: A user has many friends. A friend is a friend of many users. So it's a ManyToMany association, not a OneToMany association. Since you said Hibernate it was a OneToMany association, as soon as you're friend with Joe, no other user can be friend with Joe.